# get keys of javascript object using underscorejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How do you get the keys of a javascript object using underscorejs

I have a backbone model object that looks like this

```
 {
   lunsize: "big",
   type: {mike: "who", james: "him"},
   age: 89
}
```

In my template I have the following

```
<% var b = _.keys(this.model.attributes) %> 
<% for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++ ) { %>
<%= b[i] %>
<% } %>
```

I get the following expected output

```
lunsize
type
age
```

Although my code works as expected, am wondering is there a better way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% _.each(this.model.attributes, function(value, name) { %>
    <%- name %>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: This is the "most underscore" way of doing it, if that's important to you. It has the nice property that the iteration is internal to the library - you don't care how the iteration happens, just what action to take for each element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
for ( var prop in this.model.attributes ) {
    prop;
}
```

If you are not sure about if someone extented the Object prototype its a good thing to use `.hasOwnProperty(prop)`:

```
for ( var prop in this.model.attributes ) {
    if ( this.model.attributes.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {
        prop;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Underscore.js for this. Just use the built-in language functions `Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.forEach`.

```
<% Object.keys(this.model.attributes).forEach(function (key) { %>
    <%- key %>
<% }); %>
```

(I have also switched you from unescaped `<%=` to escape `<%-`, to avoid problems if your keys ever contain characters like `<`, `>`, `'`, `"`, or `&`.)

Comment: Underscore.js is for compatibility with older browsers.